# BST insert from Java to C

Tags: java, c, insert, binary-search-tree

I am currently learning C language and I have lots of experience in Java.

I was trying to implement the insert operation on BST and I was successfully able to accomplish it in Java, a similar code in C causes it to fail, can someone help me solve the problem please.

//Java Code (I have used  Generics, where Key is Comparable and the other generic is Value)

```
private class Node {
        private Value value;
        private Key key;
        private Node left, right;

    public Node(Key key, Value value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.key = key;
    }
}

public void put(Key key, Value value) {
    root = put(root, key, value);
}

public Node put(Node x, Key key, Value value) {

    if (x == null)
        return new Node(key, value);

    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);

    if (cmp < 0)
        x.left = put(x.left, key, value);
    else if (cmp > 0)
        x.right = put(x.right, key, value);
    else
        x.value = value;
    return x;
}
```

//C code

```
struct Node {
    int key;
    int value;
    struct Node *left, *right;
};

struct Node *root;

struct Node *put(struct Node *x, int key, int value) {

    if (x == NULL) {
        struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        return newNode;
    }

    if (key < x->key)
        x->left = insert(x->left,key,value);
    else if (key > x->key)
        x->right = insert(x->right,key,value);
    else
        x->value = value;
    return x;
}

void putMain(int key, int value) {
    root = insert(root, key, value);
}
```

Comment: `insert` should be `put` in your C code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you didn't initialize `newNode`

```
struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
newNode->key = key;
newNode->value = value;
newNode->left = NULL;
newNode->right = NULL;
return newNode;
```

Comment: That was the stupidest mistake ever, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The result of  [`malloc(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) can be `NULL` (on failure of `malloc`) or else is *uninitialized* data. you should clear and initialize it. So replace

```
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    return newNode;
```

with

```
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!newNode) { perror ("malloc node"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
    memset (newNode, 0, sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->key = key;
    return newNode;
```

BTW, you should compile with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve this in Eclipse? I am using CDT for practicing coding.

Comment: You should compile in a terminal, at least to learn how to do it. I can't help about Eclipse (and I don't recommend using it for C programming). I suggest a good editor like `emacs`